# Calling Scalar User Defined Function in Where Condition in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, user-defined-functions

I have a SQL Function `'DecryptField'` as :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DecryptField]
(
    @EField as varchar(10)
)
RETURNS varchar(10)
BEGIN

Declare @decrypted varchar(10)  
SET @decrypted = 'Something' + @EField

return @decrypted

END
```

I want to call that function in Entity Framework.(EF Version : 6.0 target framework: 4.0).
By searching over the Internet, I found a solution to create a class like :

```
public static class UDFFunctions
{
    [EdmFunction("MyModel.Store", "DecryptField")]
    public static string DecryptField(string field)
    {
       // This code will never been run against real SQL database
       // This will help any test requires this method pass
       throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported");  
    }
}
```

And then use this function as :

```
User user = null;
var query = from u in _context.Users.AsNoTracking()
            where u.Login == userName && UDFFunctions.DecryptField(u.Password) == password
            select u;
user = query.SingleOrDefault();
return user;
```

I am getting an error at runtime : `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String DecryptField(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Please tell me if I am missing anything or doing anything wrong.

Comment: Are you using EDMX file? Mapping db functions is currently supported only with EDMX. Btw. from security perspective - it is better to store hash of password (preferably with salt) instead of password which can be easily decrytped.

Comment: Yes! I am using EDMX file.